XGB find hyperparameters and then crossvalidation
I want to train an XGBoost model, and here's how I believe the process should go:
Step 1: Find the optimal hyperparameters using GridSearchCV.
Step 2: Evaluate the selected parameters.
My question is: what is the best approach to do this?
For example, I plan to first set up a dictionary of parameters and then apply GridSearchCV. But I’m unsure about how much of the dataset should be used for this step. As I understand, GridSearchCV helps in finding the best parameters, but I want to validate these parameters more thoroughly. Instead of using a hold-out set, I'd prefer cross-validation for more precise results. My idea is to apply xgb.cv() to the full dataset using the best parameters obtained from GridSearchCV.
How would you recommend proceeding to find the best parameters and then validate them through cross-validation? Would this approach be efficient?

Just to be sure: You are aware that the CV in GridSearchCV stands for cross-validation?

The process for your hyperparameter tuning with cross-validation should be:

Split dataset into training set and a test set (you could do 80/20 split, 70/30 split, etc.)
Feed the training set into the cross-validation hyperparameter tuning method (GridSearchCV, RandomSearchCV, etc.); get the model with the "best" hyperparameters.
Take the model with the "best" hyperparameters and test it on the testing set.

You could do everything in a pipeline if you would like, to reduce any chance of data leaks. This way you could do the preprocessing and other steps without data leaks.
